# Вывести на PHP текст из json

Tags: php, json

Есть вот такой json из API Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple

Как на php вывести текст из поля extract, где начинается краткий текст?

Я пробовал вот так, но ничего не работает:

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple'); 
$yummy = json_decode($url, true); 
echo $yummy['extract'];
```

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать так: `var_dump($yummy);`, прежде чем писать вопрос? Вы не знаете как работать с массивами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple'); 
$yummy = json_decode($url, true); 
$datas=$yummy['query']['pages'];

foreach($datas as $data){
  $extract =  $data['extract'];
}

echo $extract;
```

Comment: ну как вариант) если всё работает так как Вы хотели)

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем, как вывести переменную после парсинга данных, необходимо сделать её `dump` как правило, и посмотрев структуру вложенности. Если Вы не хотите это делать или по просту не умеете, но необходимо решить задачу, то воспользуйтесь онлайн преобразованием json в объект. Как мы видим на фотографии ниже, переменная extract находится в query->pages->39726->extract. Поэтому чтобы вывести данное значение Вам необходимо сделать так:
`echo $yummy['query']['pages']['39726']['extract'];` Только учитывайте тот факт, что 39726 будет меняться то и дело и надо как-то динамически выводить). Это как домашнее задание Вам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разрабатывая программы на PHP (и других языках программирования), часто приходится заглядывать в значения переменных, когда что-то идёт не так (ничего не работает). Такое заглядывание в код во время выполнения называется отладкой (или дебагом).

Самый простой способ выяснить что пошло не так в вашем случае, это посмотреть что находится в массиве к которому вы обращаетесь. Сделать это поможет функция [var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump). Просто напишите перед `echo $yummy['extract'];` `var_dump($yummy);`   посмотрите на вывод. О! Кажется вы обращаетесь не по тому ключу!

Это просто. Но не всегда удобно, когда ошибка не так очевидна. Для более серьёзных случаев удобно использовать возможности IDE для дебага. Вспомните об этом через некоторое время, когда заметите что `var_dump` уже не достаточно удобен.

Comment: Я взял пример с какого то сайта, вы можете написать просто решение для данного случая? Я в php не разбираюсь настолько. Буду благодарен.

Comment: @Stop-TussiN конечно не могу, ведь здесь не фриланс биржа. Если вы не хотите разбираться, то просто наймите человека, который сделает всё за вас.

Comment: Зачем нужен этот ресурс тогда?